# Why does my content_detail.xml doesn't show the action bar?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Forecastfragment.java

```
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by smanohar on 5/11/2016.
 */
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    private final String LOG_TAG = ForecastFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

    public ForecastFragment() {
    }


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.action_refresh){
            FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
            weatherTask.execute("94043");
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        String[] forecastArray = {"Today - Sunny 88/63",
                "Tomorrow - Sunny 70/64",
                "Sunday - Sunny 80/64",
                "Monday - Sunny 99/70",
                "Tuesday - Sunny 89/64",
                "Wednesday - Sunny 88/65",
                "Thursday - Sunny 99/76",
                "Friday - Sunny 87/89",
                "Saturday - Sunny 87/79"
        };

        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

        mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast, R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,weekForecast);

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_forecast);

        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String forecast = mForecastAdapter.getItem(position);
                Intent viewEachWeatherIntent = new Intent(getContext(),DetailActivity.class)
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, forecast);
                startActivity(viewEachWeatherIntent);
               // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), forecast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        return rootView;

    }

    /* The date/time conversion code is going to be moved outside the asynctask later,
       * so for convenience we're breaking it out into its own method now.
       */
    private String getReadableDateString(long time){
        // Because the API returns a unix timestamp (measured in seconds),
        // it must be converted to milliseconds in order to be converted to valid date.
        SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
        return shortenedDateFormat.format(time);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the weather high/lows for presentation.
     */
    private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {
        // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a degree.
        long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
        long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

        String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
        return highLowStr;
    }

    /**
     * Take the String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format and
     * pull out the data we need to construct the Strings needed for the wireframes.
     *
     * Fortunately parsing is easy:  constructor takes the JSON string and converts it
     * into an Object hierarchy for us.
     */
    private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
            throws JSONException {

        // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.
        final String OWM_LIST = "list";
        final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
        final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
        final String OWM_MAX = "max";
        final String OWM_MIN = "min";
        final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

        JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
        JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

        // OWM returns daily forecasts based upon the local time of the city that is being
        // asked for, which means that we need to know the GMT offset to translate this data
        // properly.

        // Since this data is also sent in-order and the first day is always the
        // current day, we're going to take advantage of that to get a nice
        // normalized UTC date for all of our weather.

        Time dayTime = new Time();
        dayTime.setToNow();

        // we start at the day returned by local time. Otherwise this is a mess.
        int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), dayTime.gmtoff);

        // now we work exclusively in UTC
        dayTime = new Time();

        String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
        for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
            // For now, using the format "Day, description, hi/low"
            String day;
            String description;
            String highAndLow;

            // Get the JSON object representing the day
            JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

            // The date/time is returned as a long.  We need to convert that
            // into something human-readable, since most people won't read "1400356800" as
            // "this saturday".
            long dateTime;
            // Cheating to convert this to UTC time, which is what we want anyhow
            dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay+i);
            day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

            // description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 element long.
            JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
            description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

            // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp".  Try not to name variables
            // "temp" when working with temperature.  It confuses everybody.
            JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
            double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
            double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

            highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
            resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;
        }

        for (String s : resultStrs) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast entry: " + s);
        }
        return resultStrs;

    }


 public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
            // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
            // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String forecastJsonStr = null;
            String format = "json";
            String units = "metric";
            int numDays = 7;
            String apiKey = "4fc1fba049dd6070aa4425a94a12fec7";

            try {
                // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
                // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
                final String FORECAST_BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
                final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
                final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
                final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
                final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";
//                final String apiKey = "&APPID=" + ;

                Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                        .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                        .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                        .appendQueryParameter("APPID" , apiKey)
                        .build();


                URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Built URI " + builtUri.toString());

                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }
                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast JSON String: " + forecastJsonStr );

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
                // to parse it.
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }

            }

            try{
                return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr, numDays);
            }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
         if(result != null){
             mForecastAdapter.clear();
             for(String dayForecastStr: result){
                 mForecastAdapter.add(dayForecastStr);
             }

         }
     }
 }
}
```

DetailActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.detail, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_detail, container, false);
            if(intent != null && intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)){
                String forecastStr = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_text)).setText(forecastStr);
            }
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

forecastfragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_refresh" android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

details.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

**In the DetailActivity I don't see the action bar. How to fix that?**

PS: This is how my AndroidManifest.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.sunshine.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:parentActivityName=".DetailActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Since you are only asking about showing the actionbar, I fail to see why adding a fragment with JSON parsing is necessary. Please provide a [mcve]. (Which since you say you are new in Android, is the one Activity you are having problems with, the manifest, and the styles.xml)

Comment: make `app:showAsAction="never"` as `app:showAsAction="always"`

Comment: @am110787 I changed it in detail.xml and still no change. Should I change some where else?

Comment: In all the menu xml you should have it set to `always` to make it visible.

Comment: Ok. What it does is, it shows "Setting" and "Refresh" in Action bar itself rather than showing after clicking ... . So I changed it back. My issue, I am not seeing the Action bar itself when I click one of the list item in ListView.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

goto resources folder->values->style.xml and define like this

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

</style>
```

And then goto Manifest file and add android:theme="" attribute for application tag

Comment: I have two styles.xml . One says styles.xml and styles.xml(v21). The former one is already as you said and the latter one is like this

<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
Where should I add your change and how does it fix the issue? Please help . I am a newbie to android.

Comment: You have to add this attribute in style.xml and not in v21